# Error moving files in xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I made an application on `Xcode`. I made a mistake moving my files in an other folder and now this error appeared :

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/ViewAlbum.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/homePage.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/MasterTableViewController.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/AddViewController.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/MedecineDetails.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/Medecine.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/LoginViewController.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/RegisterViewController.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/AppDelegate.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/DetailViewController.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/ViewPhoto.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/coeimac1/Desktop/learning 5535512147/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/UserLoginandRegistration/MedecineTableView.swift'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I removed all the files in the right folder but it still not working.I don't understand why it cannot find My files that are actually in the place indicated in the error..

My files in Product (the `.app` and the `.xctest`) appear in red.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: Just remove the files that appear in red in Xcode. Then drag those files from finder into Xcode. They will be added again.

Answer (score 10):

Moving files from a directory to another may change their paths. So a quick fix for that is to select the file from the `Project navigator` view, then from the `File inspector`, set the `Location` to `Relative to Project`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem adding source files in build settings and in repository.
[image: uncommitted change]

To resolve : Tap on untracked file -> open file inspector on left side Xcode Navigation Bar -> in the bottom click ADD !
And in result you will see like on the last image our file added in GIT.

[image]